# How to add ajax post query send

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Please, help solve my problem.
Is an example of a site jQueryUI - http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists

Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Sortable - Connect lists</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  #sortable1, #sortable2 {
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    width: 142px;
    min-height: 20px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 0 0 0;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  #sortable1 li, #sortable2 li {
    margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    width: 120px;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
      connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
    }).disableSelection();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
</ul>

<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 5</li>
</ul>


</body>
</html>
```

I need to send a ajax post request to the server when you add the element in sortable1 and sortable2. How to this make? Thanks.

Comment: So listen for the update event

Comment: prophecy: you'll be soon warned about SO rules and etc. better, describe your problem more explicitly. and add some code pieces what've you done so far. also, better remove the first sentence because the SOnazis will punish you for this :)

Comment: You need an ajax call when change the sequence of item in the sortable1 list?

Comment: Yes. And call ajax request change sortable2 too.

Comment: For that you can use 
$( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).bind( "sortchange", function(event, ui) {
  console.log("change event");
 //Do ajax call here
});

Comment: Because there is NO documentation on jQuery's website for this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for sortable1 and then repeat it for sortable2.

```
var length1 = $("ul#sortable1 > li").length;
$("#sortable1").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
    if ($("ul#sortable1 > li").length >= length1) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "some Url",
            data: {parameter values},
            success: function(data) {
            },
            dataType: "html",
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            error: function() {
                alert("Process Not Finished");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make ajax call on change of the sequence in sortable1 and sortable2 list as below.

```
$( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).bind( "sortchange", function(event, ui) {
   $.ajax({
        url: "some Url",
        data: {parameter values},
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data) {
        }.
        error: function() {
            alert("Process Not Finished");
        }
    });
});
```